# red border in textbox if it is not fiiled using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create a textbox, and if the user haven't filled it, the border of textbox will turn red.

```
if ($('#TextBoxID').val() == '') {
    $('#TextBoxID').css('border-color', 'red');
}
else {
    $('#TextBoxID').css('border-color', '');
}
```

I have succeed to do it by this code. However, It only turn into red when the page loaded first time. What I want is, right after the user type something in it, the red border will turn into normal. Anyone can tell how to do it dynamically?

Comment: Catch the `keypress` event of the input

Comment: you need to add an event listener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the `input` event and in the handler call this function

```js
$('#TextBoxID').on('input', function() {

  const input = $(this);

  if(input.val()) {
     input.css('border-color', '');
  } else {
     input.css('border-color', 'red');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="TextBoxID">
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a single function to handle the logic, then on page load, call it and after that suscribe to the *keyup* event

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  let myTarget = '#TextBoxID'
  const changeBorder = () => {
    if ($(myTarget).val() == '') {
      $(myTarget).css('border-color', 'red');
    } else {
      $(myTarget).css('border-color', '');
    }
  }
  // First run when page load.
  changeBorder()
  // Suscribe event
  $(myTarget).on('keyup', changeBorder)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="TextBoxID" name="myTextBox">
```

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone can tell how to do it dynamically?

Just do the same on `keyup`/`input` event

```
$('#TextBoxID').on( "keyup input", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $this.val() == '') {
        $this.css('border-color', 'red');
    }
    else {
        $this.css('border-color', '');
    }
});
```

`keyup` event will be fired when *user enters value via keyboard*, while `input` will be fired when *user enter details via mouse alone*.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load this snipped 2 times. 
First on document ready & Second on onkeypress on input-field

```
$(function() {
    if ($('#TextBoxID').val() == '') {
        $('#TextBoxID').css('border-color', 'red');
    } else {
        $('#TextBoxID').css('border-color', '#ddd');
    }

    $('#TextBoxID').onkeypress(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
        } else {
            $(this).css('border-color', '#ddd');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery `keypress , input` event on `input textbox`

```
var $textBox = $('#TextBoxID');
$textBox.on('keypress input',function(){
if ($textBox.val().length > 0) {
       $textBox.css('border-color', '');
}
else{
       $textBox.css('border-color', 'red');
}
});
```